# database join issue in pentaho

Tags: sql, pentaho

I want to execute the statement "select ID from AKTABLE where INSTANCE in ?"

I have tried  the below method. But it is not working. How can we solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was reading your comment from the other question and didn't notice you'd already turned it into a new question.

Anyway, here's the comment:

First a SQL `IN` clause requires the value list to be in `()`. Second, from what I can see, it looks like you're only comparing with a single value. In that case, just use `=` instead of `IN`. If you had say 3 values, then you could use `IN (?, ?, ?)` and configure three parameters in the 'parameters to use' section.

EDIT:

Here is an example of a transform that uses an `IN` clause in a `Database join` step. It works perfectly on my system. The `Generate Rows` step generates a single row with a single column called 'seed' and gives it my parameter value.

[image]

Comment: Actualy , I have added () in the figure using "Add constants", [bracesL,bracesR] . Also, my "temp" variable has the data  (Texas_1,Texas_2) .

Comment: The problem is you can't parameterize the entire `IN` clause. Only the individual values. You shouldn't need the `Calculator` step; just use the column value directly as in my updated example. Sorry the picture's too small for me to make out its name.